# stdclass could not convert int error Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Client ->

```
public function GetProductByProductId($productId)
{
    $this->setUrl('https://api.example.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl');
    self::$_parameters['productId'] = $productId;
    return self::$_sclient->GetProductByProductId(self::$_parameters);
}
```

Controller ->

```
$service_id = 100;
$productsRaw = $serviceClient->GetProductList();
foreach($productsRaw as $productId){
   $prd = (new serviceClient($service_id))->GetProductByProductId($productId->id);
   if ($prd->result->status == 'failure') {
       $prd = new stdClass();
       $prd->title = $productId->productName;
       ...ect
       $prd->save();
   }
}
```

I keep getting the error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in"

Comment: Could you provide the error message as a whole (so especially the part after "in")

Comment: You have two different objects called "$prd" in that code. One is a `serviceClient` object, the other is a `stdClass` object. Neither can be used in maths, which your error message suggests you are attempting (but the code shown doesn't include). Check your code carefully, and use clearer variable names to keep track of the different things you are working with.

Comment: @Seregmir ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in Client.php:233  
                                                                                                                             
(  client.php 233 -> return self::$_sclient->GetProductByProductId(self::$_parameters);  )